# Keyboard response slows down and USB mouse stops moving (Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: nvidia, keyboard, mouse

I have a desktop computer with MD® Fx(tm)-8350 eight-core processor × 8, 16 GiB RAM, and GeForce GT 630/PCIe/SSE2 graphics card. About two weeks ago I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 (which was working perfectly for almost 4 years) to Ubuntu 20.10. I am now facing problems. USB Mouse pointer stalls frequently, sometimes it even stops moving. When typing in the Text Editor, cursor does not follow my key strokes. Similarly, but less frequently, when using LibreOffice Writer or Calc the cursor lags behind. It is very frustrating. I would appreciate an advice on what to do to solve this problem other than reinstalling 18.04 back. Thanks.